# Why folder appear as binary file on external hard drive?

Tags: linux, external-hard-drive, files-folders

I have an old external hard drive, some of the folders appear as "binary"  work files and can't be opened (some other folders do not have problem).

The HD:
`Filesystem type: msdos`

Concerned folder appear as:

`Type: Binary (application/octet-stream)`

I'm using linux ubuntu. How can I recover it?

Comment: What is the filesystem? Please [edit] and provide more details (output of `ls -l` in the parent directory, `file troublesome_file`).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I edit the post thanks!

Comment: This looks like a very old DOS disk. Try to use it on Windows, or on Linux you could try [WINE](https://wiki.winehq.org/Main_Page).

Comment: This looks like a virus, when original files and folders moved to a hidden folder, and binary files were created in their place. check your files with an antivirus or upload them to virustotal

Comment: @harrymc I previously try on a windows computer (from friend, I do not have access anymore) It was the same problem

Comment: @zersh Some folders on the same disk work well without any problem, just few of them got this strange this strange problem...

Comment: and if you open such a folder with text editor,, what will it have in the headers?
the first 10-20 lines

Comment: What is the names of these folders/file?

Comment: @zersh I got something:  0\00\A4a\A1L9\92;W\00.\91\92;\DCK\00\00\00\00..         \00\A4\00\91\92;\92;\00\00\00\91\92;\00\00\00\00\00\00A.\00D\00S\00_\00S\00\00\CDt\00o\00r\00e\00\00\00\FF\FF\00\00\FF\FF\FF\FFDS_STO~1   "\00\B2f\A1L9+?W\00\B7\B1:pQT\00\00A.\00_\00.\00D\00S\00\00\A7_\00S\00t\00o\00r\00e\00\00\00\00\00\FF\FF_~1     DS_"\00\B2\00\91\92;+?W\00\00\91\92;oQ\00\00\00B5\000\00 \00A\003\00\00.\00p\00d\00f\00\00\00\FF\FF\00\00\FF\FF\FF\FFa\00f\00f\00i\00c\00\00h\00e\00_\00e\00p\00s\00\00\00_\001\00AFFICH~1PDF \00\B59l79+?\EB\009l79\91\8B½K\00B_\001\005\000\00 \00 etc... I

Comment: @harrymc, some regular names (in french, without accent or special charaters) like "DocumentMoisAvril", "Copie Clef USB", etc...

Comment: Is it possible that these are encrypted files? I would guess that at least "Copie Clef USB" is a TrueCrypt folder. If that's indeed the case, it would be impossible to decrypt without the key.

Comment: @harrymc No I called it this way. I was working fine few years ago. I just  do not use it for long time and now I have this problem.

Comment: If it wasn't like that before, then the next guess is that disk is corrupted. See [recovery products](https://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-data-recovery-file-undelete-utility.htm).

Comment: Since it is so old it should be no so wide: create an image on your HDD. Then you can try to mount it and investigate without risking to increase damages on your old HDD. I'm afraid you can face some physical failures.  Among the attempts you can try to mount the image on DOSbox, VirtualBox... if it worked under pure DOS you can always use a DOS virtual machine and mount the file as virtual HDD. Under which system did it work?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be sure not to lose your data, create a backup of the source device first.

Try the following command in the Linux terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install dosfstools
sudo dosfsck -w -r -l -a -v -t /dev/xxxx
```

**xxxx** is the partition you want to check.

- `-w` means write to disk immediately.
- `-r` means to do disk check interactively (ask you what to do to when encountering errors). On newer versions of **dosfsck** this is the default.
- `-l` means to list the filenames processed.
- `-a` means automatically fix errors. Do not use it, if You want to have more control over fixing possible errors.
- `-v` means verbose mode. Generates slightly more output.
- `-t` means mark unreadable clusters as bad.

You can find other solutions/tools here - https://askubuntu.com/questions/147228/how-to-repair-a-corrupted-fat32-file-system/147237#147237